# The input value of TextField is equal to the array list value, but the value won't be reported. why?

Tags: java, arraylist

Email that I enter in TextField in this section of code is exactly equal to the email in one of the accounts in the array list, but every no has is true. Where is the problem??

```
 boolean has = false;
            for (Account value : accounts) {
                if (value.email == email.getText().trim() && value.password == password.getText().trim()) {
                    has = true;
                }
            }
```

Comment: Because you are trying to compare a string with == instead of `.equals()`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)